# Query joined on any query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a SQL query that uses information from another query. I have tested it in MSAccess and it works, but I need to move it over to SQL to write it into code and that is where I hit the wall as I do not know how to join a `SELECT` statement onto another `SELECT`.

Here are the Access queries, first query called qryReadMeRequired:

```
SELECT 
  zEdits.ID, 
  tblReadMeDocument.ID AS DocumentID
FROM zEdits, tblReadMeDocument
WHERE (((zEdits.ID)=[Forms]![frmMain]![LoginID]) 
  AND ((zEdits.WorkArea)=[Forms]![frmMain]![WorkArea]) 
  AND ((tblReadMeDocument.RequiredBy)="all")) OR (((zEdits.ID)=[Forms]![frmMain]![LoginID]) AND ((zEdits.WorkArea)=[Forms]![frmMain]![WorkArea]) AND ((tblReadMeDocument.RequiredBy)=[Forms]![frmMain]![WorkArea]));
```

The second query uses the qryReadMeRequired:

```
SELECT 
  qryReadMeRequired.ID, 
  tblReadMeRecord.ReadDate
FROM tblReadMeRecord 
RIGHT JOIN qryReadMeRequired 
  ON (tblReadMeRecord.DocumentID = qryReadMeRequired.DocumentID) 
  AND (tblReadMeRecord.PersonID = qryReadMeRequired.ID)
WHERE (((tblReadMeRecord.ReadDate) Is Null))
```

Thanks

Comment: What's with all the junk parentheses? It makes the query logic **very** hard to follow.

Comment: Also, when you say, "move it over to sql", are you talking about the SQL view within Access, or are you talking about converting this for use with Sql Server? Because those two option will produce very different answers.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the junk parentheses are Access in action - at least two brackets around everything just to make sure.

Comment: Basically I need to run the SQL from code and determine if there are unread documents. If there are then the access program will perform another action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a `subquery`. To make a subquery, you stick your full SELECT statement that represents the subquery inside parentheses in your FROM clause. Then you give it an alias:

```
SELECT qryReadMeRequired.ID,
    tblReadMeRecord.ReadDate
FROM tblReadMeRecord
RIGHT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT zEdits.ID,
            tblReadMeDocument.ID AS DocumentID
        FROM zEdits,
            tblReadMeDocument
        WHERE               
            zEdits.ID = [Forms]![frmMain]![LoginID]
            AND zEdits.WorkArea = [Forms]![frmMain]![WorkArea]
            AND (tblReadMeDocument.RequiredBy = "all" OR tblReadMeDocument.RequiredBy = [Forms]![frmMain]![WorkArea])               
    ) AS qryReadMeRequired ON tblReadMeRecord.DocumentID = qryReadMeRequired.DocumentID
    AND tblReadMeRecord.PersonID = qryReadMeRequired.ID
WHERE tblReadMeRecord.ReadDate IS NULL;
```

I also rewrote it a bit to remove the superfluous parentheses and redundant logic.